# Inserir valores a um array numpy 3D

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Olá.

Criei o seguinte *array* `numpy` conforme abaixo:

```
import numpy as np

x = [350, 500, 800, 900, 1000]
y = [1100, 900, 1250, 650, 1200]
z = [50, 150, 300, 200, 500]

arr_2d = np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
arr_2d

array([[ 350, 1100],
       [ 500,  900],
       [ 800, 1250],
       [ 900,  650],
       [1000, 1200]])
```

Depois de processar esse *array* com `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` obtive o seguinte:

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

malha = Delaunay(arr_2d)

triangulos = arr_2d[malha.simplices]
triangulos

array([[[ 800, 1250],
        [ 900,  650],
        [1000, 1200]],

       [[ 800, 1250],
        [ 500,  900],
        [ 900,  650]],

       [[ 500,  900],
        [ 800, 1250],
        [ 350, 1100]]])
```

Agora, eu gostaria de incorporar os valores de `z` ao *array* `triangulos` de forma que o novo *array* seja igual ao seguinte:

```
array([[[ 800, 1250, 300],
        [ 900,  650, 200],
        [1000, 1200, 500]],

       [[ 800, 1250, 300],
        [ 500,  900, 150],
        [ 900,  650, 200]],

       [[ 500,  900, 150],
        [ 800, 1250, 300],
        [ 350, 1100, 50]]])
```

Preciso implementar isso a um dado que possui mais de 11.000 linhas. Alguma sugestão de como proceder? Qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples parece ser criar um dicionário, onde cada par de coordenadas x, y tirado das arrays X e Y  seja a chave, e o valor de z  serja o valor correspondente.

Depois de terminadas as operações para gerar os pontos 2D, se usa esse dicionário para recuperar a coordenada Z - senão vejamos:

(Colei exatamente os exemplos que você tem acima no terminal interativo, e continuo a partir dali)

```py
In [86]: dict_z = {(px, py): pz for px, py, pz in zip(x, y, z) } 
    ...:                                                                                                                           

In [87]: tri3 = np.array(list(list(list(linha) + [dict_z[tuple(linha)] ] for linha in T) for T in triangulos)) 
    ...:  


In [88]: print(tri3)                                                                                                               
[[[ 800 1250  300]
  [ 900  650  200]
  [1000 1200  500]]

 [[ 800 1250  300]
  [ 500  900  150]
  [ 900  650  200]]

 [[ 500  900  150]
  [ 800 1250  300]
  [ 350 1100   50]]]
```

Talvez a linha "87" onde eu agrego o valor de volta tenha uma foma mais elegante de ser escrita com np.concatenate, ou np.hstack - mas desse jeito aí funciona! :-)